# what is the difference between for and foreach in my case

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have two linked tables in the database. To display, I need to substitute compatible values ​​in the collection. When I use a for loop the code works correctly, but when I use foreach I get an error that my server is already in use.

Correct case:(not working method in comments)

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Product> objList = _db.Product;
    var arr = objList.ToArray();

    //foreach (var item in objList)
    //{
    //    item.Category = _db.Category.FirstOrDefault(category => category.Id == item.CategoryId);
    //};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i].Category = _db.Category.FirstOrDefault(category => category.Id == arr[i].CategoryId);
    }

    return View(arr);
}
```

Comment: Look at the compiled IL - or use your debugger. You **have** used your debugger... right?

Comment: This looks like a classic `SELECT 1+N` query, which you should be able to avoid if you configure the system to load the categories whilst it's loading the products.

Comment: The fundamental question is why you are wiring up the navigation property manually?  EF Core does [Relationship fixup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes#relationship-fixup) automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop is iterating over the materialized `_db.Product` query, while the `foreach` is iterating over the unmaterialized query.

This is what has materialized the query with the `for` loop:

```
var arr = objList.ToArray();
```

While the foreach loop is using the unmaterialized query:

```
foreach (var item in objList)
```

The error is because `_db.Product` has yet to retrieve any data until either `.ToArray()` (or ToList) has been invoked, which retrieves all the results, whereas when just iterating over the unmaterialized query, each item is being queried in the foreach loop.

Change the foreach loop to iterate over the materialized result set by using the `arr` variable created with `var arr = objList.ToArray();`

### Edit

As noted by Olivier's comment, all of this can be replaced by using EF's [Relationship fixup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes#relationship-fixup). Something along the lines of the following should work:

```
Product[] products = _db.Product.Include(p => p.Category).ToArray();
```